# Is there a way to apply "field_with_errors" class to existing element in Rails?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm validating form data in a Rails app, and the div containing the class "field_with_errors" is throwing off my form styled with Flexbox.

Is there a way to get Rails to append the "field_with_errors" class on an existing element instead of creating a new div with it?

Example:

```
<li class="field_with_errors">
  <input .... />
</li>
```

and not

```
<div class="field_with_errors">
  <li>
    <input .... />
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do it with javascript/jQuery. How are you currently assigning the class?

Comment: Now the "field_with_errors" div is wrapped around the invalid input field by Rails. For instance, in the corresponding Model, I have validates_presence_of :email, which then wraps the email input field with the "field_with_errors" div if the form is submitted without a value.

Answer (score 0):

You should override ActionView::Base.field_error_proc. It's defined in ActionView::Base:

```
@@field_error_proc = Proc.new{ |html_tag, instance| 
  "<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe
}
```

You can change it to better suit your UI:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| "<li class='field_with_errors'>#{html_tag}</li>".html_safe }
```

Restart your server and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is what I tried before, and unfortunately, what this does is nest the offending input in an additional li tag, like this: <li><li class="field_with_errors"><input /></li></li>. This throws off my layout too.

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically replace the original classless li with the "field_with_errors" li, perhaps? (Thanks for your help!)

Comment: The removal of the #{html_tag} is an excellent idea! However, now I realize that Rails only wraps the input field and not the span tag that precedes it to label the field. Is there a way to expand the behavior to include the preceding span tag?

Comment: What I realize is what I need is something like this: `Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| "#{html_tag, class: => 'field_with_errors'}".html_safe }

Comment: Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Oddly enough, Rails interjects before the offending input tag this element: <span id="input_tag"></span>.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround to this problem (with the help of hashrocket!).

Initial code:

```
<li>
 <span>Email</span>
 <%= f.text_field :email%>
</li>
```

I added this configuration:

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new 
 { |html_tag, instance| "#{html_tag}".html_safe }
```

When I now submit the form with the invalid email input:

```
<li>
 <span>Email</span>
 <span id="input_tag"></span>  // added by Rails
 <%= f.text_field :email%>
</li>
```

Then in the css, I set the display of the new element to none but use it to target the following input field:

```
form ul li span#input_tag {
 display: none;
}

form ul li span#input_tag + input {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Not the most elegant solution, but it works for my purposes.

Any sleeker solutions would be welcomed!